# Matlab integration and variable

Tags: matlab, variables, symbolic-integration

Hello and thanks for reading this:
This question is regarding Matlab:

I need integrate this expression of two variables

```
w1=subs(diff(K,Y1),{Y1,Y2},{0.2,0.3})
```

where  K is defined as a handle function:

```
K=@(X1,X2,Y1,Y2)...
```

so w1 is a ''function'' of two variables
but Matlab says that

> ''Undefined function or method 'matlabfunction' for input arguments of
>   type 'sym' ''

If I ask for K or w1

```
which w1
```

Matlab returns

> ''w1 is a variable''

When I use dblquad the error message is

> ''If FUN is a MATLAB object, it must have an feval method.''

I know that Matlab is right  but how can I obtain the (double) integrate of w1 in the unit square?

I have tried a lot of things but I don't get it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure which variables in your code are defined as symbolic, but here's a minimal example.

Suppose I have a function handle of the kind:

```
x = @(t, a) t*a*a;
```

If I define:

```
syms t a;
```

I can get a symbolic derivative while substituting a value like in your code:

```
f = subs(diff(x(t, a), a), a, 3);
```

Note that `f` is now a symbolic variable. To convert this variable into a function handle you can use [matlabFunction](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) like so:

```
fun = matlabFunction(f);
```

Hope this helps.